# Is there a keyboard shortcut for 'Generate stub' in VS 2010?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2010

As the title states, is there a keyboard shortcut for 'Generate stub' in VS 2010?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd> it says here for "Edit.GenerateMethodStub".

However, when it displays that little blue rectangle to click on you can access that menu with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> anyway. So <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd> does work too.

You can view (and change) key bindings in Tools → Options → Environment → Keyboard.

Comment: I was unable to get M to work, but at least I can use Ctrl+. to get to the menu without the mouse. Ctrl+.,Enter - Thanks!

Comment: Pressing Ctrl+K and then M does work here on a freshly installed VS 2010 Beta (though not yet beta 2). Those are hotkeys with two keystrokes.

Comment: And yes, Ctrl+. is one of the most useful things I've discovered as that pesky little blue box is *very* hard to hit with the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

The option is called "View.ShowSmartTag" if you want to change the binding